# How to resolve unattended-upgrades on mysql?

Tags: apt, 20.04, mysql

I have 2 `mysql` updates that cannot be installed on a 20.04:

```
2 updates could not be installed automatically. For more details,
see /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log
```

I tried the following:

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-server-8.0 mysql-client-8.0

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-client-8.0 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5)
 mysql-server-8.0 : PreDepends: mysql-common (>= 5.5)
                    Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.8+1.0.4~)


$ sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade

The following packages have been kept back:
  mysql-client mysql-server
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.


$ sudo apt list mysql* --installed

mysql-apt-config/now 0.8.16-1 all [installed,local]
mysql-client/now 8.0.22-1ubuntu18.04 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1]
mysql-common/now 8.0.22-1ubuntu18.04 amd64 [installed,local]
mysql-community-client-core/now 8.0.22-1ubuntu18.04 amd64 [installed,local]
mysql-community-client-plugins/now 8.0.22-1ubuntu18.04 amd64 [installed,local]
mysql-community-client/now 8.0.22-1ubuntu18.04 amd64 [installed,local]
mysql-community-server-core/now 8.0.22-1ubuntu18.04 amd64 [installed,local]
mysql-community-server/now 8.0.22-1ubuntu18.04 amd64 [installed,local]
mysql-server/now 8.0.22-1ubuntu18.04 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1]
```

How can I resolve them?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `sudo apt list mysql* --installed`? This will show what MySQL packages might already be installed on your system, as it looks like you may have an older version that needs to be uninstalled first.

Comment: @Matigo please see my update. Would I have to uninstall the mysql-community stuff?

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have both MySQL Server and MySQL Community Server installed on your machine, which could result in a great number of conflicts. MySQL Server is the version put out by Canonical for Ubuntu, while MySQL Community Server is put out by Oracle with its own release cadence. You will need to choose one over the other and, hopefully, the one being removed will not ruin the one that remains.

The most logical way to do this would probably be to remove both MySQL Server and MySQL Community Server, then re-install the one you want to use. Your existing database files and configurations should not be lost during this process, but do have backups ready "just in case".

Here's the order that things should be done:

1. Ensure MySQL is not running:

   ```
   $ sudo service mysql status
   ```

   If you see something like this:

   ```
   ● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
        Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
        Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-02-02 06:40:54 JST; 6 days ago
      Main PID: 112265 (mysqld)
        Status: "Server is operational"
         Tasks: 157 (limit: 9204)
        Memory: 758.9M
        CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
                └─112265 /usr/sbin/mysqld

    2月 02 06:40:53 Carbon systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
    2月 02 06:40:54 Carbon systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
   ```

   Then you will need to stop the server like this:

   ```
   $ sudo service mysql stop
   ```
2. Remove the MySQL packages listed in `sudo apt list mysql* - -installed`, which you have already provided as part of your question:

   ```
   $ sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-client \
                    mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-* \
                    mysql-community-server mysql-community-server-core-* \
                    mysql-community-client mysql-community-client-*
   ```
3. You will get a very long list of packages that are about to be removed. Read through them all to make sure there are no surprises that might break other important packages running on your system. If everything is good, proceed with the removal.
4. Clean `apt`:

   ```
   $ sudo apt autoremove
   $ sudo apt autoclean
   ```
5. Re-install the MySQL version you want (for example, the Canonical-supplied version):

   ```
   $ sudo apt install mysql-server
   ```
6. Run the secure installation procedure and set a good `root` password:

   ```
   $ sudo mysql_secure_installation
   ```
7. When done, connect to MySQL remembering that in version 8.0 and above, you need `sudo` to connect as `root`:

   ```
   $ sudo mysql
   ```

   If everything to this point is good, check that your databases are still in place with `SHOW DATABASES` and consider creating an administrator account to access MySQL without needing `sudo` if you don't already have one.
8. (Optional Step) Confirm the MySQL packages installed:

   ```
   $ sudo apt list mysql* --installed
   Listing... Done
   mysql-client-8.0/focal-security,now 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
   mysql-client-core-8.0/focal-security,now 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
   mysql-client/focal-security,focal-security,now 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 all [installed]
   mysql-common/focal,focal,now 5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 all [installed,automatic]
   mysql-server-8.0/focal-security,now 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
   mysql-server-core-8.0/focal-security,now 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
   mysql-server/focal-security,focal-security,now 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 all [installed]
   ```

Hope this helps get you running again